# ArFrame_getUpdatedTrackables does not return the expected value

Tags: android, google-chrome, arcore, webxr

I am doing image-tracking based on arcore in chrome of Android, but I found that objects were flashing on the image. After troubleshooting, I found the reason was that the image could not be tracked every dozen frames. Later debugging found that the result returned by ArFrame_getUpdatedTrackables in ArCoreImpl::GetTrackedImages cannot continue to be 1 ( It is 0 every dozen frames). What is the possiable reason?
(I have turned on the WebXR incubations flags before)

I would be very happy if you could help me with these issues.